# Prove that x and y in extended Euclid's algorithm won't overflow an Integer (If a,b <= 1e8, ax+by=gcd(a,b))

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-theory

We are given a and b <= 1e8.

The extended Euclid's algorithm always finds a solution for ax+by=gcd(a,b) (assuming it exists) which can always be stored in an Int.

How to prove the x and y won't overflow an Int?

code: https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/extended-euclid-algorithm.html

Comment: They might overflow, but you will still get $ax+by=(a,b)$. Furthermore, $x,y$ satisfy $|x| \leq b/(a,b)$, $|y| \leq a/(a,b)$. This is explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Please make your question self-contained and include the specific algorithm in your question itself.